# how to set Row Filtered DataGridView to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have DataGridview that I filtered some of it's row, I need to save the new datasource to a new DataTable, for some reason my current code don't work, here how I'm trying to convert it.

```
(LogGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Type IN({0}) AND Date >= {1} AND Date <= {2} AND Content {3} '%{4}%'", typeFilter, startDate, endDate, likeQuery,keywordFilter.Text);
        this.LogGridView.Sort(this.LogGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
FilteredTable =  LogGridView.DataSource as DataTable;

 public DataTable FilteredTable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

any Idea why it is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seen here is that after applying a filter and a sort, the sourced `DataTable` is unchanged though the `DataGridView` displays as expected. This is by design. So calling:

> ```
> FilteredTable =  LogGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
> ```

Just sets `FilteredTable` to the same as the original table.

Instead, we'll create a method to:

1. Create a new table with the same columns.
2. Select the rows from the original table using the same filter string and equivalent sort string as the `DataGridView` sort.
3. For each selected row, clone the items and add them as a new row into the new table.
4. Return the new table.

As seen here:

```
private DataTable CloneAlteredDataTableSource(DataGridView dgv)
{
    DataTable dt = dgv.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dt == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    DataTable clone = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        clone.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
    }

    string order = string.Empty;

    switch (dgv.SortOrder)
    {
        case SortOrder.Ascending: order = "ASC"; break;
        case SortOrder.Descending: order = "DESC"; break;
    }

    string sort = dgv.SortedColumn == null ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0} {1}", dgv.SortedColumn.Name, order);

    DataRow[] rows = dt.Select(dt.DefaultView.RowFilter, sort);

    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    {
        object[] items = (object[])row.ItemArray.Clone();
        clone.Rows.Add(items);
    }

    return clone;
}
```

And usage:

```
(this.LogGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Type IN({0}) AND Date >= {1} AND Date <= {2} AND Content {3} '%{4}%'", typeFilter, startDate, endDate, likeQuery,keywordFilter.Text);
this.LogGridView.Sort(this.LogGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
this.FilteredTable =  this.CloneAlteredDataTableSource(this.LogGridView);
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you. This is just what I was looking for.